# Exponent with more than 1 digit

Tags: pdftex, pgfmath

How can i format an exponent with more than one digit? For example i want `$10^20$` and latex gives me 10^2 and 0.
[image]

Comment: `$10^{10}$`. Have you read any LaTeX introductory book?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner You'll save yourself a **lot** of hassle. Not just in working out how to do things, but in not developing bad habits and hacks that will eventually need to be corrected. Please :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

just use the curly braces as `$10^{20}$`.

Comment: Sorry, but answering questions which are clear duplicates isn't the best way to go.

Comment: Saved my day, thanks!